# glib2 64-bit compile fails on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, glib

I'm encountering a problem building glib-2.26.1 on a Solaris 10 box - 64-bit. Goo diligence doesn't turn anything up, but no matter what I do the build fails in the same way. I've tried using the Sun Studio compiler, gcc (SFW) to no avail.

When I compile I get the following error:

```
[root@foo glib-2.26.1]$ export CC=/opt/solstudio12.2/bin/cc
[root@foo glib-2.26.1]$ export CFLAGS="-m64"
...configure goes normally...
[root@foo glib-2.26.1]$ make

...snip...

source='gatomic.c' object='gatomic.lo' libtool=yes \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/bash ../depcomp \
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /opt/solstudio12.2/bin/cc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I.. -I../glib -I../glib -I..  -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"GLib\" -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGLIB_COMPILATION -DPCRE_STATIC -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -D_REENTRANT -D_PTHREADS  -m64 -c -o gatomic.lo gatomic.c
libtool: compile:  /opt/solstudio12.2/bin/cc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I.. -I../glib -I../glib -I.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"GLib\" -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGLIB_COMPILATION -DPCRE_STATIC -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -D_REENTRANT -D_PTHREADS -m64 -c gatomic.c  -KPIC -DPIC -o .libs/gatomic.o
"gatomic.c", line 885: warning: no explicit type given
"gatomic.c", line 885: syntax error before or at: *
"gatomic.c", line 885: warning: old-style declaration or incorrect type for: g_atomic_mutex
"gatomic.c", line 906: warning: implicit function declaration: g_mutex_lock
"gatomic.c", line 909: warning: implicit function declaration: g_mutex_unlock
"gatomic.c", line 1155: warning: implicit function declaration: g_mutex_new
"gatomic.c", line 1155: warning: improper pointer/integer combination: op "="
cc: acomp failed for gatomic.c
make[4]: *** [gatomic.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.26.1/glib'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.26.1/glib'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.26.1/glib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.26.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know where the build might be going wrong? Not sure where else to look here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this is a bug in 2.26.1. This is, of course, one of those bugs you discover 30 seconds after asking a related question. The relevant patch can be found [here on github.](http://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/diff/package/libglib2/libglib-2.26.0-fix-compilation-with-no-builtin-atomic.patch?id=6c01ef20ee96f770bf7fc0fede90b3861d529015)